# How to install an Ubuntu backup onto a PC?

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad

I have a PC running with a new install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I also have a Chromebook running 14.04 LTS and I have a backup of this install as a tar.gz file.

Is it possible to install the 14.04 backup onto my PC (I prefer the way I have it configured)? I should add the PC does not have Windows on it, just Ubuntu.

How would I do this?

Comment: what program did you use to make the backup?

Comment: Don't see why not, unless it is an ARM based chromebook. Search for how to restore a tar backup to disk, I am sure there are question here, as well as articles in Ubuntu wiki..

Comment: I made a backup with my chromebook ( inside a terminal).  It's not an arm based chromebook.

Comment: The term "backup of the install" is very ambiguous. If you merely made a backup of the / then I think restoring it on your PC will not work. In my opinion you should remove the disk from your PC, add a USB interface to it and connect it to your chromebook. Then boot your Chromebook from LiveUSB and make a diskdump (dd) from the chrome-disk to the USB-disk.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I think these is probably a lot more complicated than I anticipated.